# images not showing in internet explorer but in firefox no problem

Tags: javascript

can anyone help me please why my images is not showing on internet
explorer 6;7  but in firefox, chrome,avant, IE8 no problem at all...
http://previewagency.com/index.shtml

Comment: is this a real question, or are you just trying to collect some google juice?

Comment: Its real in that the page is obviously broken. Stackoverflow has nofollow on all the links so I don't think anyone is trying to collect "google juice"

Comment: I just checked in IE6 and didn't see any obviously missing images.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error on this line:

```
obj.style.left = theLeft + 'px' ;
```

Because you are doing this

```
setTimeout("placeIt('layer1')", 500);
```

Which leads to this

```
obj = document.getElementById(obj);
```

So whatever layer1 is, make sure there is actually an element in the DOM with that ID before you call the function.